# Rails 6 : Simple calendar + boot strap modal + simple form for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, bootstrap-modal, simple-form-for

I am building a calendar with the "Simple calendar" gem. I want the user to be able to block some time slots, within a modal.
For a better UX, it should pre-fill the date with the selected date.
I have tried to put <%= date %> as a value, but it looks like the modal only loads the first date that shows, and doesn't increment then, so it always pre-fill the date with the first day, no matter which day I choose.
Any suggestion?

```
<%= month_calendar events: @bookings+@blocked_times do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  <button id="button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-selected-date="25-07-2021" >
    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <%= simple_form_for(@blocked_time, method: :new, url: partner_blocked_times_path(@partner)) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Block slot</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <%= f.hidden_field :partner_id, value: params[:id]%>
         <div class= "date-picker">
          <%= f.input :start_time,as: :string %>
        </div>
        <div class= "date-picker">
          <%= f.input :end_time, as: :string%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean when you pick a date on calendar, the modal (or the form `simple_form_for`) will show the picked date's data, right ?  is `@blocked_time` calculated base on `date` ?

Comment: Hi,whatever date I chose,it prefills it with the first date instead of the one I chose.

Comment: could you show `@blocked_time` code, i guess that you calculate it with the first date.

Comment: `code` @bookings = @partner.bookings     
    @blocked_times = BlockedTime.where(partner_id: @partner.id)   
    @blocked_time = BlockedTime.new

Comment: and `:start_time` always the first day ?

Comment: Yes, when it loops to build the calendar, the value "date" increments, but if I click on the modal on any other date, it always use the first iteration of "date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript.

Simply define each button with a `data-date` attribute

```html
<button id="button" type="button" class="new_event_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-date="<%= date %>">
   <i class="fas fa-calendar-times" data-date="<%= date %>"></i>
</button>
```

then catch `click` event and change form according to this value

```js
const startDate = document.getElementById('blocked_time_start_time')
const endDate = document.getElementById('blocked_time_end_time')

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.new_event_button');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var date =  event.target.getAttribute('data-date');

      startDate.value = date;
      endDate.value = date;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`simple_calendar` allow you to set `start_date` as the first date of ranges of dates will be rendered on calendar, of course the events (`BookedTime`) should match with that ranges of dates so you have to query bookedtimes from the selected date.

beside that you also need to create a new `BlockedTime` for each day with `start_time` and `end_time` is that day

```rb
# model, i assume that your model name Booking
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def self.calendar(partner_id, start_time)
   @bookings = @partner.bookings # need to filter from start_time
   @blocked_times = BlockedTime.where(partner_id: @partner.id)
                     .where("start_time >= ?", start_time) 
   @bookings+@blocked_times
  end
end
# view
<%= month_calendar(start_date: selected_date,
events: Booking.calendar(partner_id, selected_date)) do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  ...
  <% new_blocked_time = BlockedTime.new(start_time: date, end_time: date) %>
  <%= simple_form_for(new_blocked_time ...
  ...
```

you could also create a [custom-calendars](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar#custom-calendars).

Comment: I tried it, and it still shows the first date on every modal

Comment: @Blaise maybe i misunderstood your idea, you mean the range of dates that be rendered on calendar do not start with the selected day but the first day, right ?

Comment: Correct.In my case it is always the first day showing on the calendar,instead of the one I clicked on

Comment: @Blaise i updated my answer, i assume that `the one I clicked on` is `selected_date`, you need to set option `start_date` is that day, you also need to query bookedtime by that day.

Comment: I think we're getting closer. How would you define "selected_date" in the view then?

Comment: @Blaise pass your `the one I clicked on` (parameter) as local variable when render the view, or you could also create `@selected_date` on controller and use it on view.